# React and react-chartjs-2, Line chart display data with string(text)

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I wanted to create a chart to display info/days. Where I wanted to display text onY-axis. I have created line  using React.js. Currently I am able to display digit on Y-axis. However, is there a way to display string(text) on Y-axis?

In the link, the picture of the expamle what i want to do.

[my expamle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs28U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a lot of time trying to implement chartjs to my project. But i had a lot of problems with customizations. As a result i've replaced chart library to [victory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/victory) And it will suite for all your cases. I recommend you to try it and don't waste your time on chartjs